# Simple argument to prove connectedness/disconnectednes of $\mathbb R^n\setminus \mathbb R^m$.

Tags: general-topology

I thought about the standard fact from topology which says that

$\mathbb R^{n}\setminus \mathbb R^m$, where $\mathbb R^n$, $\mathbb R^m$ have standard Euclidean topologies and $$\mathbb R^m=\{(x_1,\ldots,x_m,0,\ldots,0)\in \mathbb R^n\mid x_i\in \mathbb R\}$$ is

- path-connected in case $n-m\geq 2$
- divides into two components in case $n-m=1$ (it is clear that in case $n=m$ we get empty set which is out of interests here.)

> What is most suitable pure topological (simple to follow, but rigorous) argument to show these  facts in first topology course?

I mean the argument suitable if we, for instance, are not assuming neither knowledge of dimension theory nor linear spaces staff as orthogonal sub-spaces and etc.

Good reference will be appreciated as well.

Comment: make pictures and work with coordinates directly, without mentioning words like linear spaces (but you could use line segments). Like form a path consisting of points $(x_1,\ldots,x_{n-2},u,v)$ where $u,v$ take suitable values, never simultaneously $0$, thus avoiding $\Bbb R^m$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Name $A =\mathbb R^{n}\setminus \mathbb R^m$

**Case $n-m=1$**

You have $A = A^+ \cup A^-$  and $A^+ \cap A^- = \emptyset$ where
$$\begin{cases}
A^+ = \{x \in A \mid x_n >0\} = \varphi^{-1}(\mathbb R_+)\\
A^- = \{x \in A \mid x_n <0\} = \varphi^{-1}(\mathbb R_-)
\end{cases}
$$

with $\varphi$ the linear form $\varphi: (x_1, \dots, x_n) \mapsto x_n$. Both $A^+,A^-$ are convex hence path connected (and connected).

**Case $n-m \ge 2$**

Consider two points $P_1=(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ and $P_2=(y_1, \dots, y_n)$ in $A$. $(x_{n-1}, x_n)$ and $(y_{n-1},y_n)$ are two points in $D = \mathbb R^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\}$. Those two points can be connected with a path composed of at most two line segments in $D$: $[P_1,U] \cup [U,P_2]$ with $U = (u_1,u_2) \in D$.

The path consisting of the two line segments
$$\begin{cases}
[(x_1, \dots , x_n),(0, \dots, 0, u_1,u_2)]\\
[(0, \dots, 0, u_1,u_2)],(y_1, \dots , y_n)]
\end{cases}$$
joins $P_1$ to $P_2$ in $A$.

Comment: Your solution for the $n-m \ge 2$ case is nice but for the $n-m=1$ case I thought that using a (true) statement such as 'convex sets are path connected' was exactly the kind of thing OP tried to avoid. You also don't prove that the whole space is actually not connected.

Comment: @quarague $A$ is trivially not connected in the case $n-m=1$ as it is the disjoint union of open subsets.

Comment: Then put that sentence in the answer :-)

Comment: @quarague If you read well, it is already there: $A^+,A^-$ are exactly about that.

Comment: Replace the $>$ in the definition of $A^+$ by a $\ge$. You still get two sets that are disjoint, convex and path connected. Nevertheless their union is connected. Only if you include that the sets are both open you have enough to prove that the whole space is disconnected.

Answer (score 2):

Following Mirko's suggestion in the comment, I think the easiest way to go here is to prove the statements directly. For $n-m \ge 2$ you can pick $2$ generic points and exhibit a path connecting them explicitly. For $n-m=1$ you can show that any path in $\mathbb{R}^n$ connecting the two components will have to pass through $\mathbb{R}^m$ by the intermediate value theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some more details. For $n=m+1$ prove that $(0,...,0,1)$ and $(0,...,0,-1)$ are in different components. Note that $\Bbb R^n_+:=\{(x_1,...,x_n):x_n>0)\}$ and $\Bbb R^n_-:=\{(x_1,...,x_n):x_n<0)\}$ each is a nonempty closed-and-open subset in the relative topology of $\Bbb R^n\setminus \Bbb R^m$ (and $\Bbb R^n_-\cup\Bbb R^n_+=\Bbb R^n\setminus \Bbb R^m$). Alternatively (using that $\Bbb R^n\setminus \Bbb R^m$ is open, so connectedness would be the same as path-connectedness) use that by the Intermediate value theorem 
(as pointed out in the answer by quarague) any path between $(0,...,0,1)$ and $(0,...,0,-1)$ would have to contain a point with $x_n=0$ which belongs to $\Bbb R^m$.

When $n\ge m+2$, take two arbitrary points $A=(x_1,...,x_{n-2},p,q)$ and $B=(y_1,...,y_{n-2},r,s)$ each in $\Bbb R^n\setminus \Bbb R^m$. There are some easy cases, e.g. if $pr>0$ then take the straight line segment between $A$ and $B$, it avoids $\Bbb R^m$. But, in all cases, we have $(p,q)\neq(0,0)\neq(r,s)$. The problem boils down to finding a path in $\Bbb R^2$ between $(p,q)$ and $(r,s)$ that avoids the origin. This would be easiest done with pictures, and sample (interesting) cases, e.g. if $p<0<r$ and $q=s=0$ then take a line segment from $(p,0)$ to $(p,1)$, then from 
$(p,1)$ to $(q,1)$, then from $(q,1)$ to $(q,0)$. You could incorporate (somewhere in the above procedure) also taking a line segment in $\Bbb R^m$ from 
$(x_1,...,x_{n-2})$ to $(y_1,...,y_{n-2})$.